# Download and Save PDF for viewing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Im trying to download a PDF document from my app and display it in IBooks or at least make it available to read some how when its completed downloading.

I followed the download example from Xamarin which allows me download the PDF and save it locally. Its being save in the wrong encoding also.

This is what I've tried so far.

```cs
private void PdfClickHandler()
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();

    webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) => {
        var text = e.Result; // get the downloaded text
        string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        string localFilename = $"{_blueways}.pdf";
        // writes to local storage
        File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(documentsPath, localFilename), text); 

        InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
            new UIAlertView("Done", "File downloaded and saved", null, "OK", null).Show();
        });
    };

    var url = new Uri(_blueway.PDF);
    webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    webClient.DownloadStringAsync(url);
}
```

Comment: use DownloadDataAsync or DownloadFileAsync.  DownloadStringAsync is for text, not binary files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use `DownloadStringAsync` for "binary" data, use `DownloadDataAsync`:

> Downloads the resource as a Byte array from the URI specified as an asynchronous operation.

```cs
private void PdfClickHandler ()
{
    var webClient = new WebClient ();

    webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += (s, e) => {
        var data = e.Result;
        string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        string localFilename = $"{_blueways}.pdf";
        File.WriteAllBytes (Path.Combine (documentsPath, localFilename), data);
        InvokeOnMainThread (() => {
            new UIAlertView ("Done", "File downloaded and saved", null, "OK", null).Show ();
        });
    };
    var url = new Uri ("_blueway.PDF");
    webClient.DownloadDataAsync (url);
}
```

Comment: Unless you know the size of the file you're downloading (*and* that it is small) you better download it into a file (or risk running out of memory).

Comment: I tried the same no error nothing but, file isn't saving.

Answer (score 0):

// Retrieving the URL
var pdfUrl = new Uri("url.pdf"); //enter your PDF path here

// Open PDF URL with device browser to download
Device.OpenUri(pdfUrl);

Comment: Doesn't work on the majority of Android devices... The whole purpose of downloading the PDF locally is to skip this problem

Answer (score -1):

**//First Create Model Class FileDownload**

```
public class FileDownload
{
    public string FileUrl { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

//Create a view in xaml file for button on which we need to perform download functionality

```
 <ImageButton BackgroundColor="Transparent"    Clicked="DownloadFile_Clicked" x:Name="ImgFileReportDownload_ViewResult" IsVisible="False">
                        <ImageButton.Source>
                            <FontImageSource Glyph="&#xf019;"
                                         Color="#1CBB8C"
                                         Size="30"
                                         FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}">
                            </FontImageSource>
                        </ImageButton.Source>
                    </ImageButton>
```

//Created a method in xaml.cs to download File on the click of button

```
    private async void DownloadFile_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        var status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();
        if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(fileReportNameViewResult);
            string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);


            FileDownload fileDownload = new FileDownload();
      
            fileDownload.FileName = filename;
            fileDownload.FileUrl = fileReportNameViewResult;
            MessagingCenter.Send<FileDownload>(fileDownload, "Download");
        }
        else
        {
            status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();
            if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Permission Denied!", "\nPlease go to your app settings and enable permissions.", "Ok");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

//In MainActivity.cs , create a method

```
 private void MessagingCenter()
    {
        Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Subscribe<FileDownload>(this, "Download", (s) =>
        {
            NotificationID += 4;
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Service.DownloadManager));
            intent.PutExtra("url", s.FileUrl);
            intent.PutExtra("name", s.FileName);
            _layout.SetMinimumHeight(3000);
            _layout.Bottom = 350; ;

            Snackbar.Make(_layout, "Document is Downloading.", Snackbar.LengthShort)


                         .Show();
            StartService(intent);
        });
    }
```

//Create a class DownloadManager.cs in Service folder , copy all the below code and paste , just change the Namespace

```
                                                                    using Android.App;
                                            using Android.Content;
                                            using Android.OS;
                                            using Android.Runtime;
                                            using Android.Views;
                                            using Android.Widget;
                                            using System;
                                            using System.Collections.Generic;
                                            using System.IO;
                                            using System.Linq;
                                            using System.Net;
                                            using System.Text;
                                            using System.Threading.Tasks;
                                            using Xamarin.Forms;

                                            namespace App.Droid.Service
                                            {
                                                [Service]
                                                public class DownloadManager : Android.App.Service
                                                {
                                                    AndroidNotificationManager NotificationManager = new AndroidNotificationManager();
                                                    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
                                                    {
                                                        return null;
                                                    }
                                                    public override void OnCreate()
                                                    {

                                                    }
                                                    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
                                                    {            
                                                        Task.Run(() =>
                                                        {
                                                            int messageId = ++MainActivity.NotificationID;

                                                            string url = intent.GetStringExtra("url");
                                                            string filename = intent.GetStringExtra("name");
                                                            string extension = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf('.'));
                                                            if (!filename.EndsWith(extension))
                                                            {
                                                                filename += extension;
                                                            }
                                                            NotificationManager.ScheduleNotification(filename, "", messageId);
                                                            String TempFileName = "";

                                                            try
                                                            {
                                                                HttpWebRequest Http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                                                                WebResponse Response = Http.GetResponse();
                                                                long length = Response.ContentLength;
                                                                var stream = Response.GetResponseStream();

                                                           

                                                                string baseDir = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).AbsolutePath;

                                                                //string baseDir = Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).AbsolutePath;

                                                                //string baseDir = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);                  

                                                                //string baseDir = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                                                                baseDir = Path.Combine(baseDir, filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf('/') + 1).Replace(' ', '_'));
                                                                Directory.CreateDirectory(baseDir);

                                                                //string filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, name);

                                                                if (filename.Length > 18)
                                                                {
                                                                    TempFileName = filename.Substring(0, 18) + "...";
                                                                }
                                                                else
                                                                {
                                                                    TempFileName = filename;
                                                                }
                                                                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(baseDir, filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf('/') + 1).Replace(' ', '_')));

                                                                var fis = fi.OpenWrite();
                                                                long count = 0;

                                                                int begpoint = 0;


                                                                bool iscancelled = false;
                                                                MessagingCenter.Subscribe<CancelNotificationModel>(this, "Cancel", sender =>
                                                                {
                                                                    if (messageId == sender.ID)
                                                                    {
                                                                        iscancelled = true;
                                                                    }
                                                                });
                                                                while (true)
                                                                {
                                                                    try
                                                                    {
                                                                        if (iscancelled == true)
                                                                        {
                                                                            break;
                                                                        }
                                                                        // Read file
                                                                        int bytesRead = 0;
                                                                        byte[] b = new byte[1024 * 1024];
                                                                        bytesRead = stream.Read(b, begpoint, b.Length);
                                                                        
                                                                        if (bytesRead == 0)
                                                                            break;
                                                                        fis.Write(b, 0, bytesRead);
                                                                        fis.Flush();

                                                                        count += bytesRead;
                                                                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(count + "-" + length);
                                                                        if (count >= length)
                                                                            break;
                                                                        NotificationManager.ChangeProgress(TempFileName, (int)((count * 100) / length), messageId);

                                                                    }
                                                                    catch (Exception ex)
                                                                    {
                                                                        Http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

                                                                        WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = Http.Headers;
                                                                        Http.AddRange(count, length - 1);

                                                                        Response = Http.GetResponse();

                                                                        stream = Response.GetResponseStream();
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                                fis.Close();

                                                                NotificationManager.RemoveNotification(messageId);
                                                                if (iscancelled == false)
                                                                {

                                                                    new AndroidNotificationManager().DownloadCompleted(filename, "Download Completed", Path.Combine(baseDir, filename), ++messageId);
                                                                }

                                                            }
                                                            catch (Exception ex)
                                                            {
                                                                NotificationManager.RemoveNotification(messageId);

                                                                NotificationManager.FileCancelled(filename, "Download Cancelled, Please try again", ++messageId);
                                                            }
                                                        });


                                                        return StartCommandResult.NotSticky;

                                                    }
                                                  
                                                    public override void OnDestroy()
                                                    {

                                                    }

                                                }
                                                public class CancelNotificationModel
                                                {
                                                    public int ID { get; set; }
                                                }
                                            }
```

//Create a class AndroidNotificationManager.cs in Service folder

```
                    using Android.App;
                    using Android.Content;
                    using Android.OS;
                    using Android.Runtime;
                    using Android.Views;
                    using Android.Widget;
                    using AndroidX.Core.App;
                    using System;
                    using System.Collections.Generic;
                    using System.Linq;
                    using System.Text;
                    using Xamarin.Essentials;
                    using AndroidApp = Android.App.Application;

                    namespace App.Droid.Service
                    {
                        public class AndroidNotificationManager
                        {
                            const string channelId = "default";
                            const string channelName = "Default";
                            const string channelDescription = "The default channel for notifications.";
                            const int pendingIntentId = 0;

                            public const string TitleKey = "title";
                            public const string MessageKey = "message";

                            bool channelInitialized = false;

                            NotificationManager manager;
                            NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
                            public event EventHandler NotificationReceived;

                            public void Initialize()
                            {
                                CreateNotificationChannel();
                            }

                            public void RemoveNotification(int messageid)
                            {
                                manager.Cancel(messageid);
                            }
                            public int ScheduleNotification(string title, string message, int messageId, bool isInfinite = false)
                            {
                                if (!channelInitialized)
                                {
                                    CreateNotificationChannel();
                                }



                                Intent intent = new Intent(AndroidApp.Context, typeof(MainActivity));
                                intent.PutExtra(TitleKey, title);
                                intent.PutExtra(MessageKey, message);

                                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(AndroidApp.Context, pendingIntentId, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

                                builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(AndroidApp.Context, channelId)

                                    .SetContentTitle(title)
                                    .SetContentText(message)
                                                         .SetPriority(NotificationCompat.PriorityLow)
                                    .SetVibrate(new long[] { 0L })
                                    .SetProgress(100, 0, isInfinite)
                                     .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.checkcircle);


                                var notification = builder.Build();
                                manager.Notify(messageId, notification);

                                return messageId;
                            }


                            public void ChangeProgress(string filename, int progress, int messageId)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    var actionIntent1 = new Intent();

                                    actionIntent1.SetAction("Cancel");
                                    actionIntent1.PutExtra("NotificationIdKey", messageId);
                                    var pIntent1 = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Android.App.Application.Context, 0, actionIntent1, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

                                    var ProgressBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(AndroidApp.Context, channelId)
                                    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.checkcircle)
                                     .SetContentTitle(filename)
                    .SetVibrate(new long[] { 0L })
                    .AddAction(Resource.Drawable.checkcircle, "Cancel", pIntent1)
                                         .SetPriority(NotificationCompat.PriorityLow)
                                 .SetProgress(100, progress, false)
                                .SetContentText(progress + "%")
                                .SetAutoCancel(false);

                                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(progress);
                                    manager.Notify(messageId, ProgressBuilder.Build());
                                }
                                catch
                                {

                                }
                            }
                            public void DownloadCompleted(string filenametitle, string Message, string filepath, int messageId)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    if (!channelInitialized)
                                    {
                                        CreateNotificationChannel();
                                    }

                                    var CompletedBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(AndroidApp.Context, channelId)

                                          .SetContentTitle(filenametitle)
                                          .SetContentText(Message)
                                          .SetAutoCancel(true)
                                           .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.checkcircle);

                                    Intent it = OpenFile(filepath, filenametitle);
                                  

                                    if (it != null)
                                    {
                                        PendingIntent contentIntent =
                                             PendingIntent.GetActivity(AndroidApp.Context,
                                                       pendingIntentId,
                                                       it,
                                                       PendingIntentFlags.OneShot

                             );

                                        CompletedBuilder.SetContentIntent(contentIntent);

                                       
                                    }
                                    var notification = CompletedBuilder.Build();

                                    manager.Notify(messageId, notification);
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                }
                            }
                            public void FileCancelled(string filenametitle, string Message, int messageId)
                            {

                                if (!channelInitialized)
                                {
                                    CreateNotificationChannel();
                                }

                                var CompletedBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(AndroidApp.Context, channelId)

                                      .SetContentTitle(filenametitle)
                                      .SetContentText(Message)
                                      .SetAutoCancel(true)
                                       .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.checkcircle)
                                      .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.Sound | (int)NotificationDefaults.Vibrate);

                                var notification = CompletedBuilder.Build();
                                manager.Notify(messageId, notification);
                            }
                            public void ReceiveNotification(string title, string message)
                            {
                              
                            }

                            void CreateNotificationChannel()
                            {
                                manager = (NotificationManager)AndroidApp.Context.GetSystemService(AndroidApp.NotificationService);

                                if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
                                {
                                    var channelNameJava = new Java.Lang.String(channelName);
                                    var channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelNameJava, NotificationImportance.Low)
                                    {
                                        Description = channelDescription
                                    };
                                    manager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
                                }

                                channelInitialized = true;
                            }
                            public Intent OpenFile(string filePath, string fileName)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    string application = "";
                                    string extension = fileName.Substring(fileName.IndexOf('.'));

                                    switch (extension.ToLower())
                                    {
                                        case ".doc":
                                        case ".docx":
                                            application = "application/msword";
                                            break;
                                        case ".pdf":
                                            application = "application/pdf";
                                            break;
                                        case ".xls":
                                        case ".xlsx":
                                            application = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                                            break;
                                        case ".jpg":
                                        case ".jpeg":
                                        case ".png":
                                            application = "image/jpeg";
                                            break;
                                        case ".mp4":
                                            application = "video/mp4";
                                            break;
                                        default:
                                            application = "*/*";
                                            break;
                                    }

                                    Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(filePath);
                                    bool isreadable =
                                   file.SetReadable(true);
                                    string ApplicationPackageName = AppInfo.PackageName;
                                    var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
                                    var component = new Android.Content.ComponentName(context, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(AndroidX.Core.Content.FileProvider)));
                                    var info = context.PackageManager.GetProviderInfo(component, Android.Content.PM.PackageInfoFlags.MetaData);
                                    var authority = info.Authority;
                                    Android.Net.Uri uri = AndroidX.Core.Content.FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Android.App.Application.Context, authority, file);
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
                                    System.IO.File.AppendAllText((filePath + "backdebug.txt"), System.Environment.NewLine + "Point 3 uri done ");

                                  


                                    intent.SetDataAndType(uri, application);


                                    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
                                    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NoHistory);
                                    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

                                    System.IO.File.AppendAllText((filePath + "backdebug.txt"), System.Environment.NewLine + "Point 4open file last ");



                                    return intent;
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    Intent it = new Intent();
                                    it.PutExtra("ex", ex.Message);
                                    System.IO.File.AppendAllText((filePath + "backdebug.txt"), System.Environment.NewLine + "Point 4 uri done " + ex.Message);

                                    return it;

                                }


                            }

                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is the sample code to download file in PCL Xamarin from remote server.
I have used PCLStorage library package which is available in Nuget. You just need download and install in your project.

```
 public  async void Downloadfile(string Url)
    {
        try
        {
            Uri url = new Uri(Url);
            var client = new HttpClient();


            IFolder rootfolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
            IFolder appfolder = await rootfolder.CreateFolderAsync("Download", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            IFolder dbfolder = await appfolder.CreateFolderAsync("foldername", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            IFile file = await dbfolder.CreateFileAsync(strReport_name, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            using (var fileHandler = await file.OpenAsync(PCLStorage.FileAccess.ReadAndWrite))
            {
                var httpResponse = await client.GetAsync(url);
                byte[] dataBuffer = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                await fileHandler.WriteAsync(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```